# Click the list view item to show an another list view in separate activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

- I created the listview.That was shown below.
- you can see that `listview_array[]` contains Test,Category1
  and Category2.

**ListActivity.java:**

```
package com.steph.listview;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;
    private String listview_array[] = { "Test", "Category1", "Category2", "Category3"};

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)

    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.list1);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


            }


        });
    }
}
```

**list1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

- My problem is if I click the `Test` in ListView.Following names have to shown in the new ListView: Test1,Test2 and Test3.
- Then If I click the `Category1` in ListView.Following names have to shown in the new ListView: Video1,Video2 and Video3.
- Then If I click the `Category2` in ListView.Following names have to
  shown in the new ListView: Audio1,Audio2 and Audio3.
- I doesn't know what to do.I can create an another three seperate
  Classes for Test,Category1 and Category2.And then I need to use
  intent.
- But my problem is how can I do it in single class.Help me if you have any suggestion.Thank You.

Comment: You want that when you click test then test,category1,category 2 get replaced by test1,test2 and test3?

Comment: You still didn't answer my question. Do you want to replace the old ListView's items with the new ones or something else?

Comment: @user3249477 no.I get an output like that.There if I click the Test,New listView have to created and shown the Test1,Test2,Test3.Likewise Then If I click the Category1 in ListView.Following names have to shown in the new ListView: Video1,Video2 and Video3.

Then If I click the Category2 in ListView.Following names have to shown in the new ListView: Audio1,Audio2 and Audio3.

I doesn't know what to do.I can create an another three seperate Classes for Test,Category1 and Category3.And then I need to use intent.

But my problem is how can I do all these process in `single class`.

Comment: How do you want to display this 'new ListView' ? Maybe what you want is an [ExpandableListView](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-E4hhhKZJCeg/Ue5q2WSiuJI/AAAAAAAAAko/SO-sfbDN-SM/s400/e1.png)?

Comment: no normal listview @user3249477

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56891/discussion-between-stephen-and-user3249477).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altough i have no idea why you want to load a *new instance* of this activity when you could *re-use it*, here's a working example of what you want:

```
package com.steph.listview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by Simon on 14.7.7.
 */

public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;
    private String[] groupArray = {"Category1", "Category2", "Category3"};
    private String[][] childArray = {{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"},
            {"Video1", "Video2", "Video3"}, {"Audio1", "Audio2", "Audio3"}};

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.list1);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        String[] data = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("strArray");
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener clickListener = null;

        // If no data received means this is the first activity
        if (data == null) {
            data = groupArray;
            clickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("strArray", childArray[position]);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
        }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load the item based on your position ,you no need to create different class .Single class is enough

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) 
            {
            String list_item=(String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent intent=new Intent(this,IntentListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("List_item",list_item);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
    });
```

IntentListactivity.java

```
package com.steph.listview;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class IntentListactivity extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;

               String[]  test_array={"test1","test2","test3"};
                 String[] video_array={"Video1","video2","video3"};

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)

    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.list1);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String list_value = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("List_item");
        if("Test".equals("list_value"))
         {
          lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, test_array));
         }
         else if("Category1".equals("list_value")
         {
             lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, video_array));
         }

        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Intent intent=new Intent(this,Open_task_activity.class); that was OpenTaskActivity or IntentListActivity.

Comment: Intent doesn't work.Anyway thanks for your effort."+1"

Comment: get intent return any value